# Symfony Omines DataTables Add Edit Action

Tags: symfony, datatable

I'm using the bundle Omines to create DataTables and I would like to create a button who runs an action.
When I click on this button, I would like to redirect to a user page with his user id.
How could I do that?

For example:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
public function index(Request $request, UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $table = $this->createDataTable()
            ->add('login', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Login'])
            ->add('name', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Nom'])
            ->add('school', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Ecole'])
            ->add('region', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Région'])
            ->add('limitDate', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Date Limite'])
            ->add('status', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Status'])
            ->add('actions', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Actions'])
            ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
                'entity' => User::class
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
        return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('users/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'UsersController',
        'datatable' => $table
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add button - add link with route to user page with coressponding user id. You can try to add css classes, so the link is styled as button.

```
$table
    ->add('id', TextColumn::class, ['render' => function($value, $context) {
        return sprintf('<a href="/user/%u">User page</a>', $value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `$this->generateUrl('user_page_route_name', [ROUTE PARAMS])` instead of writing url by hand

So your result should looks like :

```
$table
    ->add('id', TextColumn::class, ['render' => function($value, $context) {
        return sprintf('<a href="%s">User page</a>', $this->generateUrl('user_page_route_name', [ROUTE PARAMS]));
    });
```

By this way, you avoid to have error when your user page url change